# Finding a file based on who owns it and size (Linux)

Tags: linux

Im looking for a file on a server.

I know what user owns it, I know what group owns it, and I know its 33 bytes long.

Im not sure where on the server it is.

What is the best command I can use in order to locate this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, it is `find`.

```
find / -user alice -group wonderland -size 33c
```

Further reading: [man find](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/find.1.php)